# Vlookup to return lowest value instead of first found value

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am looking for a way for vloopup to return lowest date from the range of values but it by default returns first value in the range. Is there a better way to use vlookup to return lowest value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(B1:B6),B1:C6,1)
```

assuming your dates are from B1 to B6:

[image]